# How to connect properly to an Optivote device through a local socket connection?

Tags: flash, sockets, serial-port

Optivote IR8 is basically a voting system with a bunch of remote controllers, which can send IR signals to a receiver, which is connected to a computer through a USB port. And I'm trying to write my own little software for that with Flash.

Optivote receiver communicates with software through a virtual serial port. When I connect to that port through PuTTY, I can see signals whenever I press any button on the remote controllers.

Although, when I connect to that port through [Serproxy](http://www.lspace.nildram.co.uk/freeware.html) (which relays a socket connection to a serial port connection), the remote controllers don't seem to work. I just get the same signal every half a second or so, over and over. I'm guessing the receiver is trying to make some kind of handshake this way.

The thing I can't figure out is what PuTTY does that Serproxy doesn't to make the serial port connection work. Maybe there's some proper way to tell the other end when I connect?

(I use Serproxy, because Flash applications cannot connect to a serial port directly, but supports socket connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I could not get serproxy to work, that was until I came across a new version

http://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/TinkerProxy

Comment: Thanks, but I actually got rid of this problem by using [Serial to Ethernet Connector.](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/) It's commercial though. Didn't have the chance to use TinkerProxy.